# Update Android Studio 3.2 Cannary

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio shows an update for 3.2 canary 2, but when i click download it forward to a old build 3.1. Is the 3.2 out?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html

Comment: @TimCastelijns when i go to this link only show me the version 3.1 cannary 8. What can be?

Comment: I see it on that linked page too. It may be a staged rollout, so you may see it soon if you don't already.

Comment: Tha's strange cause happened with the 3.2 cannary 1 too. So i am in 3.1 beta 1 still.